# Where to change this code to make two titles show up in one list

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a website that I took over from someone else (who no longer works here) and one thing that my customer wants me to do is include two types of titles in a list. The website is for a law firm, and the list is a list of attorneys by title. We have one partner that's listed as the "managing partner" for his title, while the rest of the partners are simply just "partner". I want to make it where the managing partner shows up on the partner list.

What I want is for the one attorney that has the title managing partner to show up in the partner list instead of his own list. Here is the ASP/code (it was all done in one file):

This is for attorney.asp

```
count = 1
ch = "A"
while (count <= 26)
    strSQL2 = "Select * FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE LASTNAME LIKE '%"&ch&"%_' ORDER BY LASTNAME"
    set r2 = d2.Execute(strSQL2)

    if (r2.EOF = True) and (r2.BOF = True) then
    else
    %>
                            <a href="attorneys-list.asp?ch=<%= ch %>"><%= ch %></a> 
    <%          
    end if
    count = count + 1

    Select Case count
        Case 2
            ch = "B"
        Case 3
            ch = "C"
        Case 4
            ch = "D"
        Case 5
            ch = "E"
        Case 6
            ch = "F"
        Case 7
            ch = "G"
        Case 8
            ch = "H"
        Case 9
            ch = "I"
        Case 10
            ch = "J"
        Case 11
            ch = "K"
        Case 12
            ch = "L"
        Case 13
            ch = "M"
        Case 14
            ch = "N"
        Case 15
            ch = "O"
        Case 16
            ch = "P"
        Case 17
            ch = "Q"
        Case 18
            ch = "R"
        Case 19
            ch = "S"
        Case 20
            ch = "T"
        Case 21
            ch = "U"
        Case 22
            ch = "V"
        Case 23
            ch = "W"
        Case 24
            ch = "X"
        Case 25
            ch = "Y"
        Case 26
            ch = "Z"
    End Select
wEnd
 %>     
                    </p>

                    <form id="theform" name="theform" action="attorneys-list.asp" method="get">

                        <div class="fleft">
                        <label for="txt_fname">First Name</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="txt_fname" id="txt_fname" /><br />
                        </div>

                        <div class="fleft">
                        <label for="txt_lname">Last Name</label><br />
                        <input type="text" name="txt_lname" id="txt_lname" /><br />
                        </div>

                        <div class="fleft">
                        <label for="sel_title">Title</label><br />
<%
strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM ATTNY_TITLES"
set r2 = d2.Execute(strSQL2)
r2.movefirst
%>
                        <br /><select name="sel_title" id="Select1">
                            <OPTION value=""></OPTION>
                            <OPTION value="1">Partner</OPTION>  
                            <OPTION value="2">Associate</OPTION>    
                            <OPTION value="3">Of Counsel</OPTION>   
                            <OPTION value="4">Managing Partner</OPTION>
                            <OPTION value="6">Senior Counsel</OPTION>

                        </SELECT>
                        </div>

                        <div class="fleft">
                        <label for="sel_school">School</label><br />
<%
strSQL2 = "SELECT DISTINCT SCHOOL FROM ATTNY_EDUCATION ORDER BY SCHOOL"
set r2 = d2.Execute(strSQL2)
r2.movefirst
%>
                        <select name="sel_school" id="sel_school" style="width:230px;">
                            <OPTION value=""></OPTION>
<%          
while (r2.EOF = false) and (r2.BOF = false)
    %>
                            <OPTION value="<%= r2("SCHOOL") %>"><%= r2("SCHOOL") %></OPTION>
    <%
    r2.movenext
wEnd
 %>         
                        </SELECT><br />
                        </div>

                        <div class="fleft">
                        <label for="sel_practice_group">Practice Group</label><br />
<%
strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM FIRM_PRACTICE_GRPS ORDER BY PRACTICE_GRP"
set r2 = d2.Execute(strSQL2)
r2.movefirst
%>
                        <select name="sel_practice_group" id="sel_practice_group" style="width:180px;">
                            <OPTION value=""></OPTION>
<%          
while (r2.EOF = false) and (r2.BOF = false)
    %>
                            <OPTION value="<%= r2("PRACTICE_GRP_ID") %>"><%= r2("PRACTICE_GRP") %></OPTION>
    <%
    r2.movenext
wEnd
 %>         
                        </SELECT><br />
                        </div>

                        <div class="fleft">
                        <label for="sel_services">Services</label><br />
<%
strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM AOE_UNIQUE ORDER BY AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE"
set r2 = d2.Execute(strSQL2)
r2.movefirst
%>
                        <select name="sel_services" id="sel_services"  style="width:230px;">
                            <OPTION value=""></OPTION>
<%          
while (r2.EOF = false) and (r2.BOF = false)
    %>
                            <OPTION value="<%= r2("ID") %>"><%= r2("AREAS_OF_EXPERTISE") %></OPTION>
    <%
    r2.movenext
wEnd
 %>         
                        </SELECT><br />
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div><!-- class="fleft" -->
                        <input type="submit" value="Search Attorneys" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
                        <input type="button" value="All Attorneys" onclick="allAttorneys();" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the code for the search results (attorneys-list.asp):

```
<div class="content">
                <img src="img/hero_attorneys.jpg" width="480" height="153" alt="Attorneys" border="0" id="hero" />
                <h1>Attorney Search Results</h1>
                <div class="content_body">
                <p> 
                <table class="atty">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <!--<th>VCard</th> -->
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
<%
                if (ch <> "") then
                    strSQL = "Select * FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE LASTNAME LIKE '"&ch&"%' OR LASTNAME LIKE '% "&ch&"%' ORDER BY LASTNAME"
                    set r1 = d1.Execute(strSQL)

                     if (r1.EOF = True) and (r1.BOF = True) then
                    %>
                        No results
                    <%
                    else
                        r1.movefirst
                        while (r1.EOF = false) and (r1.BOF = false)
                            FullName = r1("NAME") & " " & r1("INITIAL") & " " & r1("LASTNAME") & " " & r1("Suffix")
                            strSQL5="SELECT * from ATTNY_TITLES WHERE TITLE_ID LIKE "&r1("TITLE_ID")
                            set r5 = d2.Execute(strSQL5)
                            if (r5.EOF = True) and (r5.BOF = True) then

                            else
                                r5.movefirst
        %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="attorney-bio.asp?AttorneyID=<%= r1("ATTY_ID") %>"><%= FullName %></a></td>
                        <td><%= r5("ATT_TITLE") %></td>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><%= r1("TEL") %></td>
                        <!--<td><a href="vcards/<%= r1("VCARD") %>">VCard</a></td> -->
                        <td><a href="mailto:<%= r1("EMAIL") %>"><%= r1("EMAIL") %></a></td>
                    </tr>
        <%         
                            end if
                            r1.movenext
                        wend       
                    end if          
                elseif (firstName="") and (lastName="") and (title="") and (school="") and (practiceGroup="") and (services="") then
                    strSQL = "Select * FROM ATTORNEYS ORDER BY LASTNAME"
                    set r1 = d1.Execute(strSQL)

                     if (r1.EOF = True) and (r1.BOF = True) then
                    %>
                        No results
                    <%
                    else
                        r1.movefirst
                        while (r1.EOF = false) and (r1.BOF = false)
                            FullName = r1("NAME") & " " & r1("INITIAL") & " " & r1("LASTNAME")
                            strSQL5="SELECT * from ATTNY_TITLES WHERE TITLE_ID="&r1("TITLE_ID")
                            set r5 = d2.Execute(strSQL5)
                            if (r5.EOF = True) and (r5.BOF = True) then

                            else
                                r5.movefirst
        %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="attorney-bio.asp?AttorneyID=<%= r1("ATTY_ID") %>"><%= FullName %></a></td>
                        <td><%= r5("ATT_TITLE") %></td>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><%= r1("TEL") %></td>
                        <td><a href="mailto:<%= r1("EMAIL") %>"><%= r1("EMAIL") %></a></td>
                    </tr>
        <%         
                            end if
                            r1.movenext
                        wend       
                    end if            
                else
                    if (title = "") then
                        strSQL = "Select * FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE ((NAME LIKE '"&firstName&"%') AND (LASTNAME LIKE '%"&lastName&"%')) ORDER BY LASTNAME"
                    else   
                        strSQL = "Select * FROM ATTORNEYS WHERE ((NAME LIKE '"&firstName&"%') AND (LASTNAME LIKE '"&lastName&"%') AND (TITLE_ID="&title&")) ORDER BY LASTNAME"                        
                    end if
                    set r1 = d1.Execute(strSQL)

                    if (r1.EOF = True) and (r1.BOF = True) then

                    else
                        r1.movefirst
                        while (r1.EOF = false) and (r1.BOF = false)   
                             if (school = "") then
                                strSQL2 = strSQL
                            else   
                               strSQL2 = "Select ATTY_ID FROM ATTNY_EDUCATION WHERE ((SCHOOL='"&school&"') and (ATTY_ID="&r1("ATTY_ID")&"))"                   
                            end if

                            set r2 = d2.Execute(strSQL2)

                            if (r2.EOF = True) and (r2.BOF = True) then

                            else
                                r2.movefirst

                                if (practiceGroup = "") then
                                    strSQL3 = strSQL2
                                else
                                    strSQL3 = "Select ATTY_ID FROM ATTNY_PRACTICE_GROUPS WHERE PRACTICE_GRP_ID="&practiceGroup&" AND ATTY_ID="&r1("ATTY_ID")&""
                                end if

                                set r3 = d1.Execute(strSQL3)
                                if (r3.EOF = True) and (r3.BOF = True) then

                                else
                                    r3.movefirst
                                    if (services="") then
                                        strSQL4 = strSQL3
                                    else
                                        strSQL4 = "Select * FROM AOE_ATTY WHERE AOE_UNIQUE_ID="&services&" AND ATTY_ID="&r1("ATTY_ID")&""

                                    end if

                                    set r4 = d2.Execute(strSQL4)

                                    if (r4.EOF = True) and (r4.BOF = True) then

                                    else
                                        r4.movefirst


                                                count = count + 1   
                                                FullName = r1("NAME") & " " & r1("INITIAL") & " " & r1("LASTNAME")
                                                strSQL5="SELECT * from ATTNY_TITLES WHERE TITLE_ID="&r1("TITLE_ID")
                                                set r5 = d2.Execute(strSQL5)
                                                if (r5.EOF = True) and (r5.BOF = True) then

                                                else
                                                    r5.movefirst
        %>

                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="attorney-bio.asp?AttorneyID=<%= r1("ATTY_ID") %>"><%= FullName %></a></td>
                        <td><%= r5("ATT_TITLE") %></td>
                        <td nowrap="nowrap"><%= r1("TEL") %></td>
                        <td><a href="mailto:<%= r1("EMAIL") %>"><%= r1("EMAIL") %></a></td>
                    </tr>

        <%                  
                                                end if 
                                    end if
                                end if
                            end if
                            r1.movenext
                        wend 
                    end if
                    if (count = 0) then
                    %>
                        No results
                    <%
                    end if

                end if
%>          
                </table>
                </p>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Where in the world do I make the changes to the code? I tried creating another field in the ATTNY_TITLES table called TITLEID (as opposed to TITLE_ID) and making the options for partner and managing partner the same value "1", but that didn't work. Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: Wow, that's a bit of a mess! I suspect you want to be editing this line... `strSQL5="SELECT * from ATTNY_TITLES WHERE TITLE_ID LIKE "&r1("TITLE_ID")` to take into account the 2 possible title Ids (eg `TITLE_ID = 1 OR TITLE_ID = 2`. There's no need for the `LIKE`s all over the place and that code needs some serious tidying up. I'd be tempted to rewrite it from scratch as it could probably be 80-90% smaller and a lot more efficient.

Comment: This code hurts my eyes :( i'd suggest a complete re-write.

Comment: I'm sorry you had to inherit this code... it's quite scary. You may want to address the SQL injection issues in addition to fixing your current issue. The nested queries could be replaced with a single VIEW in the background with a single query for searching.

Comment: Oh and don't actually DO this, but typing the following into the last name search box would probably nuke your database... `'; DROP TABLE ATTORNEYS--` - You need to read up on "SQL injection" as a matter of urgency

Comment: @Basic: The worst part is that the change you have in your comment needs to be repeated in at least 4 other places.

Comment: @Cory Yeah I know... This code is [more than a little moist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) (link to help OP)

Comment: Oh boy.  My head hurts. This isn't ASP.NET and VB.NET, but rather Classic ASP and VB Script.  I'd retag the post to get better visibility.  I still know and support both of those and would be glad to help, but like others have pointed out, you have a lot of cleanup to do on this mess!

Comment: Yeah, I kinda felt like the code was a mess. I'm not the best coder, but all those nested ifs and whiles make it seem pretty murky to me. @Basic, I'm going to make a backup of the database and try it, lol. I've always wanted to see the [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/) comic come to life.